# Dynimcally created Select option is duplicating itself when doing selectmenu("refresh") in Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am creating select option(Drop-down) dynamically using an JSON array. It is creating a select option which also have another select option inside that.

I have created a ***select*** in my html and using the same in my JavaScript. Created ***option*** and appended to the ***select***

```
<div  id="state-template" style="display: none">

    <div id="state-container">

        <label class="state-select-label"></label>

        <select name="state-select" id="state-select"></select>

    </div>

</div>
```

And JavaScript snippet is,

```
$.each(StatesArray, function (stateIndex, stateItem){

    $("#state-select").append($("<option></option>").attr("value", stateIndex).text(""+stateItem.StateName));


});

$("#state-select").selectmenu().selectmenu("refresh");
```

It is creating a drop-down with a inner drop-down which is a duplicate. And the inner drop-down list the list of states on tap.

Followed many threads in Stackoverflow but didn't got that right.

Below are the rendered element structure image and select option in screen.

[Inspect Element - Select option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4txQ1.png)  [image]

[image]

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your error (that is, your code worked for me). Can you please tell me how/where do you call your JavaScript? Can you try calling it by pressing a button after the `select` has been created? That should help troubleshooting

Comment: My duplicate issue got fixed. Now even if I select a data, it is not visible. Am bit confused whether it is hidden or not set.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var append_data;
$.each(StatesArray, function (stateIndex, stateItem){

    append_data+= '<option value='"+stateIndex+"'>'"+stateItem.StateName+"'</option>';

});

$("#state-select").append(append_data);
```

Comment: I tried your code and it is listing the states. But on select, it is not showing the selected state on top of the select. If I do inspect element, the first option(selected value) is undefined.

Comment: You duplication problem is solved i think. And yes check its post value for correction.

Comment: @Joseph can you show me the selectbox html created after jquery append?

Comment: Here is my selectbox html after jquery append :  '<select name="state-select" id="state-select" aria-invalid="false" class="valid">undefined<option value="0">'Alabama"</option><option value="1">'Alaska"</option><option value="2">'Arizona"</option><option value="3">'Arkansas"</option></select>'

Comment: It looks fine, you might made any other mistake inside your code. and yes you can create a condition for index 0 inside your js loop

Comment: The complete code I am using is given in my query. I am still looking where I am wrong. Also why it is showing undefined before option 0. Is the value not setting ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92931/discussion-between-joseph-and-maha-dev).